# Implementing a solar charger protocol - how to deal with register definitions

Tags: rust, serial-port, protocols, uart

I would like to write a library that implements the serial (uart) communication protocol for a well known brand of solar chargers. Luckily the protocol specification is publicly available so I don't have to do any reverse engineering. The protocol is very easy: Each ascii encoded frame consists of a magic start, a register address, a command code (get or set), the payload (in case of 'get' this is omitted, otherwise the value to write) and a checksum.

My question is now: How should I deal with the dozens of register definitions? Just hardcode those as an array of structs like this:

```rust
pub struct Request {
    pub address: u16,
    pub command: u8,
    pub payload: Option<u16>,
    pub checksum: u8,
    pub description: &'static str
}

pub const REGS: &'static [Request] = &[
    Request {address: 0xabcd, command: 8, payload: Some(0x8000), checksum: 0xab, description: "Current battery voltage" },
    Request {address: 0xef23, command: 8, payload: Some(0x8080), checksum: 0xab, description: "Current (mA)"},
];
```

This way I could match on the address part of an incoming frame.
Or maybe get those from a separate .json file via serde? But this would have the drawback that my library might be difficult to use on an embedded device (no_std) that doesn't have a file system.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a look how the `hyperium` [`http`](https://docs.rs/http) crate defines some of its common `HTTP` headers, of which there are about 30-50 of.

```rust
// Generate constants for all standard HTTP headers. This includes a static hash
// code for the "fast hash" path. The hash code for static headers *do not* have
// to match the text representation of those headers. This is because header
// strings are always converted to the static values (when they match) before
// being hashed. This means that it is impossible to compare the static hash
// code of CONTENT_LENGTH with "content-length".
standard_headers! {
    /* [...] */
    (Accept, ACCEPT, b"accept");

    /* [...] */
    (AcceptCharset, ACCEPT_CHARSET, b"accept-charset");
    /* [...] */
}
```

It uses a `macro-rule` to parse some predefined syntax, let's look at the [`standard-headers`](https://docs.rs/http/0.2.9/src/http/header/name.rs.html#65) macro.

```rust
macro_rules! standard_headers {
    (
        $(
            $(#[$docs:meta])*
            ($konst:ident, $upcase:ident, $name_bytes:literal);
        )+
    ) => {
        /* [...] */

        $(
            $(#[$docs])*
            pub const $upcase: HeaderName = HeaderName {
                inner: Repr::Standard(StandardHeader::$konst),
            };
        )+

        /* [...] */
    }
}
```

Maybe we can use the existing code and rewrite it to generate the request constants.

```rust
macro_rules! define_requests {
    (
        $(
            $(#[$docs:meta])*
            ($request_name:ident, $address:literal, $description:literal);
        )+
    ) => {
        $(
            $(#[$docs])*
            pub const $request_name: Request = Request {
                address: $address,
                command: 8, 
                payload: Some(0x8000), 
                checksum: 0xab, 
                description: $description
            };
        )+
    }
}
```

Now we can define our constant request types using the macro.

```rust
define_requests! {
    (GET_BATTERY_VOLTAGE, 0xabcd, "Current battery voltage");
    (GET_MILI_AMP, 0xef23, "Current (mA)");
}
```

Check out the [`code`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c36e5aa6cc9cefe04a4b36d493b3e413). To see the generated code, select from the upper left three dots the "HIR" representation and then press the button left to it.

Comment: If you would like to parse request definitions from a JSON time at compile time, which solves your file system problem, I would recommend that you implement a proc-macro to parse said JSON file and generate the corresponding code.

Comment: Using a proc-macro could also enable you to generate checksums at compile time, if that is necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael! Always wanted to learn about rusts macro system. I will take this as an opportunity and start with the macro book.

Comment: @user2969586 if the answer satisfies your question, could you maybe mark it as so? Really don't want to be the toxic Stack Overflow user here, but we all live for the karma.

Comment: Sure, sorry for the delay! Haven't been here for a while.